# Unrecognized transform root element: Weavers

Tags: android, xamarin, realm

I added Realm through Nuget Package Manager in Xamarin binding project. But i am facing this error **Unrecognized transform root element: Weavers** after installing plugin. Error is because of FodyWeaver.xml which is getting install from Fody plugin as Fody and Realm are interlinked .

Comment: You added the Realm package to a `Xamarin.Android` *binding project*?

Comment: What are you trying to bind? I'm not sure if the `Xamarin` version of `Realm` is a re-write or port of the existing `Android` SDK. You may want to add the `Realm` tag as well.

Comment: @JonDouglas Just a FYI: `Xamarin.Realm` uses the `Cpp` version of `Realm-Core` and that is shared across all their supported platforms. The C# "wrapper" is a from scratch C# project that uses `Eody` to *weave* your C# Realm inherited DB objects to direct `Cpp` access and thus at runtime your C# code is directly managing live Cpp objects and all the unsafe/ptr magic was done at compile time (that is why their benchmarks are so dang good.. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @JohnDouglas I'm facing the same issue here. Were you able to use Realm in a Xamarin.Android binding project? I need to expose classes that inheritate from RealmObject. Thanks

Comment: @ramonesteban78 there's a [github issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/892) open where we ask for more info. Can you check it out and help us figure out what's causing the problem.

Comment: @SushiHangover ya i created a binding project and added Realm through Nuget Package

Comment: @JonDouglas i added the tag <RealmWeaver /> inside <Weaver> tag in FodyWeaver.xml